# SQLite3 terminal

Tags: ios, sqlite, terminal

How can I figure out the column names of a table using sqlite3 from the terminal on a mac? I forgot what I named the columns and I can't figure out how what the names were. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html:

`.schema {tablename}`

in the SQLite console will print out the CREATE statement.

Answer (score -1):

Just run the `.header on` it will start showing column name in select statements.